# Creating a site column using a feature and setting its WebId property

Tags: feature, site-column

I need to create a site column that will be added to children sites, this column is a lookup referencing a list in the rootWeb, so I need to provide de WebId property in order to make it available on sub-sites.

The problem is that I don't have the root web Id during the deployment and before activating the feature. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I'm working with SP 2010. Here is a sample of my XML schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">  
  <Field
   ID="{d4911cd3-63c8-4536-a136-1f50b4ea974c}"
   Name="MyColumnName"
   StaticName="MyColumnName"
   DisplayName="My Column"
   Type="Lookup"
   List="/Lists/MyList"
   ShowField="LinkTitleNoMenu"
   Required="FALSE"
   Group="MyColumns">
  </Field>
</Elements>
```

As you can see, I'm not using the WebId atribute, however the list in the sub-site that uses this site column, does not display any data.

Comment: this is an old thread, but the list url should read "Lists/MyList" instead of "/Lists" (note the missing leading slash)

Answer (score 0):

**If you are working on SP 2010**

You simply don't need to specify a value for the webId.

As per Microsoft [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798514.aspx):

> The WebId attribute specifies the internal name of the site that contains the target list. ***If the attribute is omitted or set to an empty string, SharePoint will assume that the list is on the root site of the site collection***.

So, just specify a list "url" for the List property should be enough: SharePoint will search it on the root site.

**If you are stuck with SP 2007**
Best approach would probably be creating the column programmatically via a feature receiver. That way you can save yourself from the GUID hell related to list and web id usage in a feature.